# SQL Database : Relationships & schema

Tags: sql, database, schema, relational-database

i am a student and i have a question about database schema , i already created the Entity Relationship Diagram [ERD] and in this step i should do the database schema , must all the entities on my database has a relation between them and the other entities ? i.e : each entity should have a foreign key for the entity before it , because i can create all the tables and only 2 tables can have a relation between them and i control the other tables using C# program i am going to create .

** in my ERD all the entities have a relation between each other .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...must all the entities on my database has a relation between them and
>   the other entities?

No. Entities of course can stand on their own. Although in practice if you're finding that you have very few relationships you're probably doing something wrong...

You're sort of right in saying that only two tables can have a relationship but I'd word it as a relationship can have only two participants; tables can certainly relate to more than just one other table.

Comment: really nice answer , in fact this is my second time making ERD and schema and the project i am working on it a bit big , so yeah i may be doing something wrong , and i`ll revise my work , and i like when you said that a relationship can have only two participants , i`ll keep that in mind . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Any time you create tables in the database if there is a relationship between the information in the tables then you should create a relationship to make sure that when the data is entered into the tables that the reference data will be there.  This will enforce referential integrity.  For example:

Employees Database:

```
EmployeeInfoTable:
   pk EmployeeID
      EmployeeName
      EmployeeDateHired
   fk SalaryID

EmployeeLoginTable
   pk LoginID
   fk EmployeeID
      Username
      Password

SalaryTable
   pk SalaryID
      SalaryRange
```

So what this would do is make sure that if you add a salary to an employee it has to exist in the Salary table and if you added a login then you would have to have an employee to reference.  It's just an added layer of security to make sure that the data that is being input into the database is valid and can be used.

While you can technically control this with C# or whatever programing language you want it's easy to forget these little rule especially in a database that has like 200 tables or more.  So getting in the habit of using relationships and maintaining referential integrity is a very good thing to do.

Comment: you are correct , and i am really thankful that you included a code here , because i had another question if i can use a PK on table as a FK on another table , so thanks again

Comment: An FK in a table must refer to a PK (or at least a unique key) in another table.

Comment: @R.Vector A primary key is set to that so that each row has a unique reference.  you can use this unique reference to link other tables so the employee table could be linked to 100 other tables by it's primary key(not a real world scenario) but the foreign key is just a copy of the primary key for referential purposes.

Comment: @Raihan yes a Foreign Key is by definition a reference to a primary key from another table.

Answer (score 0):

the primary key should always be `id` due to convention, and your foreign keys could be called `othertablename_id` so if a table has a link to all the other tables it will need a key for each one of those.

for example: if `dogs` has more than one owners but `owners` can only have one dog, you could just have `dog_id` in the `owner` table. but then you would have to query the `owners` table to find all the owners of one dog.

if dogs have more than one owner and owner can have more than one dog, then you have to have a join table called `dogs_owners` with id and both foreign key `dog_id` and `owner_id`

of course you can name your tables and fields whatever you want but it's convention to use `id` and `_id`

yes an entity usually equates to just one table, apart from when you have many-to-many relationships between your entities.

Comment: if you use just `id` it distinguishes the `id` of the current table and foreign keys.

Comment: i understood what you mean , and yeah you are correct . thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All entities need not have relationships with each other. A relationship will only exist between two entiries in the ERD if one entity somehow relates to the other.

The general rule of thumb for creating table is:

1. Each entity in the ERD will have a table for it
2. For a one-to-many relationship in the ERD, the many side table will contain a foreign key to the one side table
3. For a many-to-many relationsip, there will be a separate table for the relationship that will contain foreign keys to both the entity tables
4. If a relationship has an attribute, there will be a separate table for the relationship that will contain foreign keys to both the entity tables

Comment: wow , really great rules . i`ll keep them in mind of course when i am creating a database , thank you very much .

Comment: If you want, you can upvote the answers you like and accpet the one you like most.